# Web-based Subversion client that can make commits

Tags: open-source, web-apps, self-hosted, version-control, subversion

I am looking for an open source web interface for Subversion repositories that can be self-hosted on Debian or Ubuntu Linux. The web interface should be able to list and view files in the repository. In addition, it must allow specific users to edit files (via download and re-upload) and make commits through a web browser.